# Django main query ordered by subquery

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, orm, subquery

I want to make main queryset ordered by subquery list.

The relationship between models can be briefly expressed as follows.

```
class Firm(models.Model):
    cik = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=5,primary_key=True)
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

class File(models.Model):
    accNumber = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

What I want to query :

```
SELECT ticker
FROM Stock
WHERE firm_id = 
            ( SELECT firm_id, count(*) as total 
              FROM File 
              WHERE created_at >yesterday AND created at < today
              GROUP BY firm_id 
              ORDER BY total )
```

I use django.db.models.Subquery to make the nested SQL above.
Django code :

```
firm_list = File.objects\
    .filter(Q(created_at__gte=yesterday)|Q(created_at__lte=today))\
    .values('firm_id')\
    .annotate(total=Count('firm_id'))\
    .order_by('-total')

ticker_list = Stock.objects
    .filter(firm_id__in=Subquery(firm_list.values('firm_id')))
    .only('ticker')
```

I want to make ticker list ordered by firm list order. firm list order is like

```
>>>firm_list.values('firm_id')
<QuerySet [{'firm_id': 1750}, {'firm_id': 1800}, {'firm_id': 4977}, {'firm_id': 3453}]>
```

but the ticker list is not ordered by subquery.

```
>>> ticker_list.values('firm_id')
<QuerySet [{'firm_id': 1750}, {'firm_id': 1800}, {'firm_id': 3453}, {'firm_id': 4977}]>
```

How can I make the main query ordered by subquery list order?? I'm using sqlite for db. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by `Case, When` in `django.db.models`.

```
firm_list = File.objects\
        .filter(Q(created_at__gte=yesterday)|Q(created_at__lte=today))\
        .values('firm_id')\
        .annotate(total=Count('firm_id'))\
        .order_by('-total')\
        .values_list('firm_id',flat=True)

preserved = Case(*[When(firm_id=firm_id,then=pos) for pos, firm_id in enumerate(firm_list)])

ticker_list = Stock.objects\
       .filter(firm_id__in=Subquery(firm_list.values('firm_id')))\
       .order_by(preserved)
```